# python stucks when concat columns to pandas DataFrame using for loop [Segmentation fault (core dumped)]

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to subtract each value of an array from the DataFrame and want to construct new DataFrame.

I tried as below but python stucks over it and hangs my PC with forceful close of spyder I get terminal error [$ Segmentation fault (core dumped)]. It runs for small loop. I want dataframe of size (20200 by 3000) as out put. 
If there is any another way to perform this will be helpful. Thanks

```
error = np.arange(-150, 150, 0.1) ## length 3000
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(-20,2000,0.1)) ## length 20200
result = pd.DataFrame()

for i in error:
    x = data - i
    result = pd.concat([result, x], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

also, when I assign np.arange array to dataframe the float values chages. I am using python 3.6 on anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't keep concatenating at every step, its not efficient.

```
error = np.arange(-150, 150, 0.1) ## length 3000
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(-20,2000,0.1)) ## length 20200
result = pd.DataFrame()
result_list = []

for i in error:
    x = data - i
    result_list.append(x)

result = pd.concat(result_list, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you @A.Kot for providing solution.